# How can I get the signup button of my code to stay at the top?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a container for the header: `<header-container>`
In this container, there is a nav bar, the logo of my website and signup button which links to another html page.

However, when I scroll down the page, the sign up button scrolls down with it which interferes with the visuals of other aspects of the page.

I removed the `position:fixed` from signup-container, however it impacted the positioning of the navbar and the signup container. I then tried to move the values of margin-left, top etc to see if it would make any difference, it didn't. I went to inspect it via Google Chrome and the inspection says that the position:static property prevents top from having an effect and that I should try setting position to something other than static.

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Logo formatting */

.logo-container {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.logo-container img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: -180px;
}

nav a {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #383838;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
  /* Added transition for a smoother effect */
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.signup-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 20px;
}


/* Sign up button on the top right */

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 50px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #A6A6A6;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 10px 0 #A6A6A6;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="img/LUXSC2.png" alt="Page Logo">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="values.html">Values</a>
    <a href="facts.html">Facts</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="signup-container">
    <a href="logInPage.html" class="btn">Sign Up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your description what your overall layout goals are. Why is the button absolutely positioned? How is it supposed to fit with the navbar? Please revise to explain what you're trying to accomplish more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element with a fixed position is relative to the viewport. It's going to stay in the same spot no matter what moves past it on page.

I would recommend using an absolute position, and changing the CSS like so:

```
.header-container .signup-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Since the signup-container is a child of .header-container, it's good to group them up like this.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it immediately! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the above recommendation and if you are making it responsive then i would suggest you to use % instead of px

```
.header-container .signup-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: "5%";
  right: "10%";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution.